# convert bit to int forward with foldr

Tags: haskell

bit array right to left, e.g. [0,1,0,1] = 10 can be read with:

```
binToInt = foldr (\x xs -> x + 2 * xs) 0
```

I would like to read it left to right, e.g. [1,0,1,0] = 10

I thought this would work:

```
binToInt' = foldr (\x xs -> (x * ((^) 2 (length xs)) + xs) 0
```

however I get the error:

```
Couldn't match type `t0 a0' with `Int'
```

what am I doing wrong?

(as a work around I am reversing the result of binToInt)

Comment: You cannot use `xs` as an argument to `(+)`; it's a list, not the sum of the values in that list.

Comment: @chepner I think it's the opposite: in the second definition, `xs` is a number, so it can't be fed to `length`

Comment: Right; I can never keep the arguments to that function straight.

Answer (score 5):

I solved my problem:

```
binToInt' = foldl (\acc x -> x + 2 * acc) 0
```

which unfolds to:

```
f = (\acc x -> x + 2 * acc)
foldl f 0
  [1,0,1,0]
  (f [1,0,1]) * 2 + 0
  ((f [1,0]) * 2 + 1) * 2 + 0
  (((f [1]) * 2 + 0) * 2 + 1) * 2 + 0
  ((((f []) * 2 + 1) * 2 + 0) * 2 + 1) * 2 + 0
  ((((0) * 2 + 1) * 2 + 0) * 2 + 1) * 2 + 0
```